# How do we solve the recurrence $T(n) = 2T(n/3) + n^{ \log_32 }\log\log n$?

Tags: algorithms, asymptotics, recurrence-relations, analysis-of-algorithms

How do we solve the recurrence  $T(n) = 2T(n/3) + n^{ \log_32 }\log\log n$?  Also, is it possible to solve this recurrence by the Master method?

Comment: Just out of curiosity, where did you find this recurrence? It looks so weird and random that there must be some interesting mathematical story behind it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Choosing $n = 3^m$ we have

$$
T(3^m)=2T(3^{m-1})+3^{m\log_3 2}\log_3(\log_3 3^m)
$$

Now calling $\mathcal{T}(\cdot)=T(3^{(\cdot)})$ we follow with the recurrence

$$
\mathcal{T}(m)=2\mathcal{T}(m-1)+2^m\log_3 m
$$

This recurrence has as solution

$$
\mathcal{T}(m)=2^m \left(c_0 + \log_3 (m!)\right)
$$

Now, going backwards with $m = \log_3 n$ we have

$$
T(n) = 2^{\log_3 n}\left(c_0+\log_3((\log_3 n)!)\right)
$$